# Group records in Rails for a chart?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts, model

**SOLVED**

I have a pie chart:

[image]

```
data: [<% HomeworkStudent.where(:school_user_id => current_user.school_user.id).each do | homework_student| %>
            [<%= homework_student.homework.classmodule.subject.to_json.html_safe %>, <%= homework_student.difficulty.to_json %>],
            <% end %>]
    }]
```

The data is plotted fine but i'm looking to group the "difficulty" by subject. So in other words there should only be Maths and Art once on the chart. This is highcharts chart.

I have also tried the following different approach through my model but it does not work:

homework.rb

```
def self.getData
    data = []
    self.subjectnames.each do |type2|
      data << Hash["name", type2, "y", self.type2_count(type2)]
    end
    data
  end

...
private

def self.subjectnames
    Classmodule.pluck(:homework_id).uniq
  end

   def self.type2_count(type2)
    HomeworkStudent.where(difficulty: type2).count
  end
```

And then in the chart like so:

```
Controller 

@data = Homework.getData()

View: 

data: <%= @data.to_json.html_safe %>
```

The latter route is the ideal route but because different models are involved it's a bit confusing.

There are 3 models: Classmodule holds name of subject, homework_student holds difficulty column and homework_id column.

```
homework.rb
has_many :homework_students, :class_name => 'HomeworkStudent', dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :classmodule, :class_name => 'Classmodule', :foreign_key => :subject

classmodule.rb
    has_many :homeworks, :class_name => 'Homework'

homework_student.rb:
belongs_to :classmodule, :class_name => 'Classmodule', :foreign_key => :subject
```

Although not ideal and i'd prefer to do it properly my approach now at the top works but i'm just wondering how to group the results by subject? And if I have to go through the model for this any suggestions?

Thanks!

**SOLVED**

Thanks to Ruby Racer:

In controller:

```
@data = {}
        HomeworkStudent.where(:school_user_id => current_user.school_user.id).each do |homework_student|
        label = homework_student.homework.classmodule.subject
        value = homework_student.difficulty.to_i
    @data[label] = (@data[label]) ? (@data[label] + value) : value
end
```

In chart on view:

```
data: <%= @data.to_a.to_json.html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going into the models, I would go for something like this:

```
@data = {}
HomeworkStudent.where(:school_user_id => current_user.school_user.id).each do |homework_student|
    label = homework_student.homework.classmodule.subject
    value = homework_student.difficulty
    @data[label] = (@data[label]) ? (@data[label] + value.to_i) : value.to_i
end
```

Now `@data` looks a little like this:

```
@data
# {"art"=>90, "math"=>200}
@data.to_a
# [["art", 90], ["math", 200]]
```

Which is a lot like you need. Now you need only transform it to be json and html safe

```
newdata = @data.map {|subject, difficulty| [subject.to_json.html_safe, difficuty.to_json]}
```

But you don't really need that. So, you send the ruby array to js:

```
data: <%= @data.to_a.inspect.html_safe %>
```

Or, better still:

```
data: <%= @data.to_a.to_json.html_safe %>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much, I updated OP with your solution and an error I am getting...there are nil values in the difficulty column...

Comment: Simply add, `to_i`, see my updated answer. Nil to i is zero

Comment: Thanks, nearly there! data: newdata does not work so changed to data: <%= @newdata.to_json.html_safe %> and this returns data: [["\"Maths\"","26"],["\"Art\"","30"]], proper format should be like ["Maths", 26]...

Comment: In that case, I think `@data.to_a` should suffice, and use `data: @data.to_a`

Comment: Welcome, actually I guess the right thing should be `data: <%= @data.to_a %>`

Comment: I tried that but for some reason it does not work - returning: data: [[&quot;Chemistry&quot;, 8]]. When I put in the extensions though it's cleaned up?

Comment: thanks for helping. Really appreciate it. Hope you don't mind I asked a previous question here about setting a start point for a graph...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645831/highcharts-rails-way-...but got no responses. I'd really, really appreciate it if you could have a quick look if you have time? Thanks.